# aptitude upgrade linux 3.2.0-39 problem

Tags: 12.04, server, upgrade, aptitude

since yesterday I am trying to upgrade my system to the latest version. I am using Ubuntu Server 12.04.2 LTS. The strangest thing happens when I try to upgrade my system. Here is the output of **aptitude upgrade**

```
frank@spoon:~$ sudo aptitude upgrade
The following partially installed packages will be configured:
  initramfs-tools linux-generic linux-image-3.2.0-39-generic linux-image-generic linux-image-server 
No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.
Setting up initramfs-tools (0.99ubuntu13.1) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Setting up linux-image-3.2.0-39-generic (3.2.0-39.62) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
Use of chdir('') or chdir(undef) as chdir() is deprecated at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.2.0-39-generic.postinst line 235.
Failed to symbolic-link /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-39-generic to initrd.img:File exists at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.2.0-39-generic.postinst line 614.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-3.2.0-39-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 17
No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
                                                                    dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic:
 linux-image-generic depends on linux-image-3.2.0-39-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-3.2.0-39-generic is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic:
 linux-generic depends on linux-image-generic (= 3.2.0.39.47); however:
  Package linux-image-generic is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing linux-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
                                                                    No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
                                                                                                                                        dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-server:
 linux-image-server depends on linux-image-3.2.0-39-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-3.2.0-39-generic is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
                                                                    Processing triggers for initramfs-tools ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-38-generic
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/ntfs_3g failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-38-generic with 1.
dpkg: error processing initramfs-tools (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
                                                                    Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-3.2.0-39-generic
 linux-image-generic
 linux-generic
 linux-image-server
 initramfs-tools
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
A package failed to install.  Trying to recover:
Setting up initramfs-tools (0.99ubuntu13.1) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Setting up linux-image-3.2.0-39-generic (3.2.0-39.62) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
Use of chdir('') or chdir(undef) as chdir() is deprecated at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.2.0-39-generic.postinst line 235.
Failed to symbolic-link /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-39-generic to initrd.img:File exists at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.2.0-39-generic.postinst line 614.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-3.2.0-39-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 17
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic:
 linux-image-generic depends on linux-image-3.2.0-39-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-3.2.0-39-generic is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-server:
 linux-image-server depends on linux-image-3.2.0-39-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-3.2.0-39-generic is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic:
 linux-generic depends on linux-image-generic (= 3.2.0.39.47); however:
  Package linux-image-generic is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing linux-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-38-generic
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/ntfs_3g failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-38-generic with 1.
dpkg: error processing initramfs-tools (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-3.2.0-39-generic
 linux-image-generic
 linux-image-server
 linux-generic
 initramfs-tools
```

The stranges thing is when I look in my home folder I see symlinks */boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-39-generic* and to */boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-39-generic*. Here a listing of my home folder.

```
frank@spoon:~$ ls
documents  dotfiles  downloads  initrd.img  insync  Insync.bak  iso  music  shares  tmp  virtualbox  vmlinuz  wallpapers  workspace
frank@spoon:~$
```

This is a listing of my / root folder. What the hell is initrd.img.8579

```
frank@spoon:/$ ll
total 96
drwxr-xr-x  23 root root  4096 Mar 19 23:13 ./
drwxr-xr-x  23 root root  4096 Mar 19 23:13 ../
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Mar 19 21:48 bin/
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Mar 20 13:36 boot/
drwxr-xr-x  17 root root  4340 Mar 20 13:30 dev/
drwxr-xr-x 140 root root 12288 Mar 20 13:30 etc/
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Jan 22 20:43 home/
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    33 Mar  3 11:10 initrd.img.8579 -> /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-38-generic
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    33 Jan 30 21:43 initrd.img.old -> /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-36-generic
drwxr-xr-x  22 root root  4096 Mar 19 23:12 lib/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Jan 27 13:08 lib64/
drwx------   2 root root 16384 Jan 22 20:36 lost+found/
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Jan 22 20:37 media/
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4096 Mar  4 19:36 mnt/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Jan 22 20:36 opt/
dr-xr-xr-x 131 root root     0 Mar 20 13:30 proc/
drwx------   9 root root  4096 Mar 20 13:03 root/
drwxr-xr-x  22 root root   780 Mar 20 13:32 run/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Mar 19 23:12 sbin/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Mar  5  2012 selinux/
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Mar  4 20:02 srv/
drwxr-xr-x  13 root root     0 Mar 20 13:30 sys/
drwxrwxrwt  15 root root  4096 Mar 20 13:36 tmp/
drwxr-xr-x  11 root root  4096 Mar  4 20:01 usr/
drwxr-xr-x  12 root root  4096 Mar 20 13:15 var/
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    29 Mar  3 11:10 vmlinuz -> boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-38-generic
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    29 Jan 30 21:43 vmlinuz.old -> boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-36-generic
```

As I said it is very very odd. and I don't know anymore what to do, that's why I wrote the question on stackoverflow. Thanks for any help, avoiding me to have to reinstall the entire system, which would take a while.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

So I solved it by removing the cornering Debian Control Files from **/var/lib/dpkg/info/**

***Files removed***

- linux-image-3.2.0-39-generic.*
- linux-generic.*
- initramfs-tools.*

After removing the files I simply did **aptitude upgrade** again and it worked just as expected.